# Match consecutive word stems with re

Tags: python, regex

I need to match consecutive stems.

Eg if I am looking for content related to a body often called as either
 `commission of nutrition` and `committee of nutrition`,
I would like to be able to do something like this:
`comm* of nutrition`.

I can't quite figure out a regex for this.

Comment: Please give a Simple, Minimal and Reproducible Example. [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

As already being said, its not quite clear what exactly you are looking for.

It sounds like you are looking for a regex that matches your stems anywhere in a given text.

This little regex is one way to archive it

```
import re
# test-sentences
test = "some text before 'commission of nutrition' and after"
test1 = "committee of nutrition, only after"
test2 = "again before 'committee at nutrition'"

# pattern
reg = r'comm(ission|ittee) of nutrition'

# test-cases
if re.search(reg, test):
    print("match found")
else:
    print("No match found")
if re.search(reg, test1):
    print("match found")
else:
    print("No match found")
if re.search(reg, test2):
    print("match found")
else:
    print("No match found")

# results
match found
match found
No match found
```